# h5py: how to use keys() loop over HDF5 Groups and Datasets

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

`print(list(file.keys()))`

When I run this code I get:

`T00000000,T00000001,T00000002,T00000003, ... ,T00000474`

Now, I analized T00000000 but I want to scan them all with `for` loop. I couldn't do because this is a string. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what is `file`? Could you show a little more code?

Comment: This is a HDF5 file and this file include some groups as I mentioned (T00000000, ..... ,T00000474) and I did some arangements on T00000000. But I want to do same things for all of groups with for-loop.

Comment: You already have an iterator in `file.keys()`. You should be able to use `for key in file.keys():` to loop over them.

Comment: OK, thank you. I'm gonna try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the split() method.

If the string is "T00000000,T00000001,T00000002,T00000003, ... ,T00000474", you can use split to turn it on a list like this:

```
string = "T00000000,T00000001,T00000002,T00000003, ... ,T00000474"
values = string.split(",")
```

So, the list values becomes `["T00000000", "T00000001","T00000003", ... ,"T000000474"]`.

Then you can use this in a for loop.

If you don't wanto to create a list, you can simply:

```
for value in string.split(","):
     #Your code here...
```

The for loop will be execute with the values T00000000, T00000001, T00000003 ...

Answer (score 4):

@python_student, there is more to this than explained in the initial answer. Based on the syntax of you question, it appears you are using `h5py` to read the HDF5 file. To effectively access the file  contents, you need a basic understanding of HDF5 and h5py. I suggest starting here: [h5py Quick Start Guide](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html). In addition, there are many good questions and answer here on StackOverflow with details and examples.

An HDF5 file has 2 basic objects:

- **Datasets**: array-like collections of data
- **Groups**: folder-like containers that hold datasets and other groups

h5py, uses dictionary syntax to access Group objects, and reads Datasets using NumPy syntax. (Note group objects are not Python dictionaries - just just "look" like them!)

As you noted, the `keys()` are the **NAMES of the objects** (groups or datasets) at the root level of your file. Your code created a list from the group keys: `list(file.keys())`.  In general there is no reason to do this. Typically, you will iterate over the `keys()` or `items()` instead of creating a list.

Here is a short code segment to show how you might do this. I can add more details once I know more about your data schema. (HDF5 is a general data container and have most any schema.)

```
# loop on names:
for name in file.keys():
    print(name)
# loop on names and H5 objects:
for name, h5obj in file.items():
    if isinstance(h5obj,h5py.Group):
        print(name,'is a Group')
    elif isinstance(h5obj,h5py.Dataset):
        print(name,'is a Dataset')
        # return a np.array using dataset object:
        arr1 = h5obj[:]
        # return a np.array using dataset name:
        arr2 = file[name][:] 
        # compare arr1 to arr2 (should always return True):
        print(np.array_equal(arr1, arr2))
```